# Bad Status Line nginx/uwsgi/django

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I have a django app which I communicate with, using a python script. 
Sometime (about 1/500) I get strange errors.

```
https <-> nginx <-> uwsgi <-> django
```

**Rare errors in the python script:**

- http.client.BadStatusLine: ''
- urllib.error.URLError:
- ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:598)

**I cannot see any trace of those in either:**

- appLog
- uwsgi log
- nginx log

How can I begin to trace this issue?

Comment: Concerning the last error (EOF), I have noticed that it may happen if the response is an empty string.
In my case, it happens when sending binary data: in that case, the HttpResponse has both an empty string and the binary data itself.
When SSLSocket.send tries to write the empty string, it raises the above exception.
I have solved it by specifying a content in the HttpResponse constructor.